# Enforce eslint rules only on new files

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there a way to configure or customize eslint rules such that it only applies to new files being checked in? There's no autofix for the eslint rule and it's prohibitively expensive to convert older files to comply with the eslint rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

at the beginning of old files